# RequireJS: How to load multiple functions from one module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a module that needs to return 3 functions,i wrote the module like this (sorry about all the `return`s, I translated this directly from coffeescript):

```
(function() {
  define("inColor", [], function() {
    var init;
    init = function(value, obj) {
      var foundVal;
      foundVal = void 0;
      $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if (value === key) {
          foundVal = val;
        }
      });
      return foundVal;
    };
    return init;
  });

  define("fillColor", ['inColor'], function(inColor) {
    var capletColor, init;
    capletColor = {
      primary: "#3DA0DB",
      info: "#B5D1D8",
      success: "#2ECC71",
      warning: "#FFCC33",
      danger: "#E15258",
      inverse: "#62707D",
      theme: "#f37864",
      "theme-inverse": "#6CC3A0",
      palevioletred: "#913B53",
      green: "#99CC00",
      lightseagreen: "#1ABC9B"
    };
    init = function(obj) {
      var codeColor;
      inColor = inColor(obj.data("color") || obj.data("toolscolor"), capletColor);
      codeColor = inColor || obj.data("color") || obj.data("toolscolor");
      return codeColor;
    };
    return init;
  });

  define("rgbaColor", [], function() {
    var init;
    init = function(hex, opacity) {
      var b, bigint, g, r;
      bigint = parseInt(hex.replace("#", ""), 16);
      r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
      g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
      b = bigint & 255;
      if (opacity || opacity <= 1) {
        return "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + (opacity || 1) + ")";
      } else {
        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
      }
    };
    return init;
  });

  define('colorModuleLoader', ['inColor', 'fillColor', 'rgbaColor'], function(inColor, fillColor, rgbaColor) {
    return {
      inColor: inColor,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      rgbaColor: rgbaColor
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Now i load my module like this:

```
require(['tmp/assets/scripts/admin/modules/caplet.color'], function(colorModuleLoader) {
    return window.alert(colorModuleLoader.rgbaColor("#F37864", 0.1));
  });
```

The module is loaded, but error says `colorModuleLoader` is `undefined` when i try t alert the value,can anyone explain why?

Comment: You might post the coffeescript instead :-)

Comment: thank you for the input, but i found out people tend to read js instead of coffee on this site

Comment: My guess is that in case of multiple modules, and/or the explicit file require, `require.js` doesn't know your callback does expect the `colorModuleLoader` module

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as RequireJS is concerned you have four modules there, and they are all in one file. (As many modules as `define` calls.) The basic rules for proper operation of RequireJS are that you should have one module per file and your `define` calls should not name their modules. (The optimizer `r.js` adds module names.) There are *some* exceptions to these rules but you really need to know what you are doing to use these exceptions (and be able to explain why you need to do something different than the basic rule).

What you can do is to have your `tmp/assets/scripts/admin/modules/caplet.color.js` file contain one module that exports all the functions you need:

```
define(function() {

    function inColor() {...}

    function fillColor() {...}

    function rgbaColor() {...}

    return {
      inColor: inColor,
      fillColor: fillColor,
      rgbaColor: rgbaColor
    };    

});
```

Comment: Works like magic, thanks.
Anyway i noticed you are the same man who helped me in requirejs question yesterday, you are pretty cool man :)

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, since there was a discussion about Coffee Script vs JS in comments. I do appreciate that you posted in JS. (And it was a good thing to put a comment that it was translated from CS for those who would want to complain about the generated code.) I don't use CS so while I *can* read it, I find it more difficult. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do have to pull multiple modules from one file you can do it using [bundles](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) in your `requirejs.config({})` statement.

```
requirejs.config({
  bundles: {
    'tmp/assets/scripts/admin/modules/caplet.color':['inColor', 'fillColor', 'rgbaColor', 'colorModuleLoader']
  }
});

require(['inColor', 'fillColor', 'rgbaColor', 'colorModuleLoader'], function(inColor, fillColor, rgbaColor, colorModuleLoader){
  // write code here
})
```